# Setting proxy for webview

Tags: qt, qml, qwebview

I used the [webview](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qml-webview.html)  of qml to make a small browser, and it works fine.

Problem is, when there is a network with proxy set for it, it fails.

Try 1.

I read from [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Why_does_QML_require_QDeclarativeNetworkAccessManagerFactory) about the QDeclarativeNetworkAccessManagerFactory class and tried to set proxy only for my qml Application, but it did not work.

Try 2.

I read and tried to set the Application wide proxy with this code:

```
    QNetworkProxy proxy;
    proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
    proxy.setHostName("proxy.foo.com");
    proxy.setPort(8080);
    proxy.setUser("itsme");
    proxy.setPassword("really");
    QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```

But it did not work. Any idea how to proceed?

---

Edit:

I am getting this message in the output :

```
QNetworkAccessCache::addEntry: overriding active cache entry > 'auth:proxy-> > http://proxy.foo.com:8080'
```

Comment: I've never had any trouble using your second approach. What does "it did not work" precisely stand for?

Comment: @TheHuge_ Web page just remained blank instead of opening the respective page. Did you try these settings over a qml webview element specifically?

Comment: Yes. The only difference is that my proxy works without authentication.

Comment: Is your proxy receiving any connection attempt? Do they fail?